# Can you override NSDateFormatter 12 vs 24 hour time format without using a custom dateFormat

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I want to convert a Date as a display string in the user's time zone, but I want to use 24 hour time format rather than 12 hour time format.

I know I can do that by explicitly setting a custom `dateFormat` string, but that loses the benefit of letting the system generate strings that conform to the user's locale setting.

`NSNumberFormatter` has settings that let you change aspects of the conversion, like the decimal separator.

Is there a setting for `NSDateFormatter` that will let me switch between 12 and 24 hour format without having to resort to a completely custom format?

Answer (score 1):

`DateFormatter` has the `dateFormat(fromTemplate:options:locale:)` method. Use this to get a proper 24-hour format based on the user's locale.

```
let fmt = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "Hms", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)
```

Though this seems to return `HH:mm:ss` for most locales. Only 85 of the 739 available locales return something other than `HH:mm:ss`.