# DateFormatter and components order when using regex

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

If I've understood correctly, if I want to customize how a date is displayed I have two options:

1. I can use regex such as `"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"`
2. I can set `DateFormatter.Style` to `short`, `medium`, etc.

In the second case I believe that the order of the components changes according to the specific country default. For example "06 Dec" automatically becomes "Dec 06" when switching to another language with that date default.

However that's not the case when using regex, correct? So this means that if I want to customize the date format with regex, I need to provide a specific regex for each country?

Comment: `DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate:...)` could be what you are looking for – see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425664/can-you-override-nsdateformatter-12-vs-24-hour-time-format-without-using-a-custo or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767330/nsdateformatter-date-according-to-currentlocale-without-year

Comment: You can use `locale` of dateFormatter as Martin Suggest and just set `Locale.current`

Comment: Btw, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm" is a [(date format) pattern](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), not a regex.